# How to Show/Hide a Panel upon Click of a Button in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, panel

I am having issues showing up or hiding a Panel on a button click.  By default the panel is hidden but I want the panel to show up once the button is clicked and it is not working for me now.

The only time the panel shows up is when another post-back occurs, like when I select drop down and that triggers a post-back then my panel will show up.  I think the issue is that I am using an `UpdatePanel` and which is only doing a partial post back.

Here is the code where I am using `AsyncPostBackTrigger` for my control (Button).

```
<div id="dvGrid" style="padding: 10px; width: 876px">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="870px" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#C2D69B"
                    HeaderStyle-BackColor="green" ShowFooter="True" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging"
                    DataKeyNames="DEV_SK">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#C2D69B" />
                    <Columns> 
                       <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="ID" Visible = "false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDEV_SK" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DEV_SK")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="10px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                </asp:GridView>
             </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdate"  />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>  
    </div>
```

and here is the the code for the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="SAVE" OnClick = "Update" Visible = "true" 
Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Large" Height="30px" Width="157px"/>
```

and here is the code behind once they click the button:

```
 protected void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        //do somthing else

    }
```

and here is my Panel:

```
   <div>
       <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Groove" Height="109px" Visible="false"
            Width="870px" BackColor="#FFFFE1">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="SIGN" Font-Bold="True" 
                ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />

            <asp:Label ID="lblUID" runat="server" Text="User ID:"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUID" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="145px"></asp:TextBox> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;

            <asp:Label ID="lblPass" runat="server" Text="Password:"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPass" runat="server" Height="23px" TextMode="Password" style="margin-top: 0px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="183px"
                onclick="btnSubmit_Click" 
                OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');" 
                Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Medium" Height="30px" 
                style="margin-right: 1px" />
            <br />
        </asp:Panel>

    </div>
```

Comment: Where's actual `Panel1` control?

Comment: Yuriy, i just added the Panel code in my initial post.  Please look at the top

Comment: So your Panel1 is outside of your UpdatePanel?

Comment: yes it is outside of the update panel

Comment: Then the button that is designated as AsyncPostBackTrigger for an UpdatePanel will not affect it. You need to either place the panel inside of the first UpdatePanel or inside of UpdatePanel of its own

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the IDs of you DOM elements, you can achieve this by using JQuery.

```
<head>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js' >
<script>

  $(document).ready( function() {
     $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {
          $('#Panel1').toggle(); //Show or Hide
          e.preventDefault(); 
     });

  });
</script>
```